# unable to run openstack tempest testcases in group

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, openstack, testr

i have created one sampletest.txt file in tempest folder and written tempest test case location in that file.

now i want to run that file using testr or nosetest so that all the test case present in that file get executed..
example
contents in sampletest.txt file

tempest.api.identity.admin.test_users:UsersTestJSON.test_create_user_with_enabled

tempest.api.identity.admin.test_roles:RolesTestJSON.test_role_create_delete

tempest.api.identity.admin.test_roles:RolesTestJSON.test_get_role_by_id

tempest.api.identity.admin.test_roles:RolesTestJSON.test_remove_user_role

now i want to execute this sampletest.txt file so that all the testcase get executed...
if i am executing this file nosetests -vx sampletest.txt , i am getting error

Answer (score 1):

Try to use tilt and cat the file Eg:

```
 nosetest -vx `cat sampletest.txt`
```

Please make sure to configure your etc/tempest.conf are as below,

```
  [identity]
  uri=http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/
  uri_v3 = http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/
  auth_version=v2
  admin_domain_name = Default
  admin_tenant_name = admin
  admin_password = {your_openstack_admin_login_password}
  admin_username = admin
  tenant_name = {non-admin-tenant-eg-demo}
  username = {non-admin-user-eg-demo}
  password = {non-admin-user-password}

  [dashboard]

  login_url=http://127.0.0.1/auth/login/
  uri_v3 = http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/
```

If still you are getting any errors please post your error logs.

You can also refer my post :http://naggappan.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/configure-and-execute-tempest-in-openstack-environment/